# Insert html befor </body> tag jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to insert a paragraph element `<p>` at the end of `<body>`, just before the `</body>`.

I've tried `insertBefore()` as follow, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertBefore( "</body>" );
```

Answer (score 13):

This means that you want to `append` content to the `<body>`. [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will add the content to the end of the selector element.

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$(document.body).append("<p>Test</p>");
```

```css
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Downvoter, do you mind explain why? Can something be improved?

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
.append();
```

From the jQuery API for .append( ):

"Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements." (http://api.jquery.com/append/)

So

```
$('body').append("<p>Test</p>");
```

will insert the html to the end of body which is before the closing tag < /body>.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

`$("body").append("<p>Test</p>")`

or

`$("<p>Test</p>").appendTo("body")`

They both do the same thing, but the second is more useful if also wanting to save the created element:

```
var $test = $("<p>Test</p>").appendTo("body");
// Do something else here
$test.css("background", "red");
```

See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) for more information.